# java.io.File and paths in Linux and Windows

Tags: java, linux, windows, file-io, cross-platform

I wrote a little programm, which takes path to a directory from the command prompt and prints all files and catalogs that are placed in this directory. But it works fine only for Windows. I have something like this:

```
path = args[0];    
File dir = new File(path);
System.out.println(dir.listFiles());
```

Launch at Windows (works fine):

```
java MyProg C:\mydir
```

Launch at Linux:

```
java MyProg /home/user/mydir
```

And instead of a list of files I get this:

```
[Ljava.io.File;@190690e
```

What am I doing wrong and where my cross-platform?

---

UPD: Yes, it was my mistake with printing array. But:
Why it works differently with different directories? With first dir programm works fine, with second I got nullptr

```
maxim@maxim-VirtualBox:~$ java FileSearch /home/maxim/Downloads/archives/
maxim@maxim-VirtualBox:~$ java FileSearch /home/maxim/Install/
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at FileSearch.saveFilesInList(FileSearch.java:21)
    at FileSearch.saveFilesInList(FileSearch.java:25)
    at FileSearch.saveFilesInList(FileSearch.java:25)
    at FileSearch.saveFilesInList(FileSearch.java:25)
    at FileSearch.saveFilesInList(FileSearch.java:25)
    at FileSearch.saveFilesInList(FileSearch.java:25)
    at FileSearch.saveFilesInList(FileSearch.java:25)
    at FileSearch.saveFilesInList(FileSearch.java:25)
    at FileSearch.main(FileSearch.java:88)
```

Here is my function:

```
    private static void saveFilesInList(String path, ArrayList<String> files)
                throws IOException
    {
            File dir = new File(path);
            File[] list = dir.listFiles();

[21]        for (File f : list) {
                if (f.isFile()) {
                    if (isUnic(f.getName(), files)) files.add(f.getName());
                } else {
[25]                saveFilesInList(f.getCanonicalPath(), files);
                }
            }
    }
```

both dirs have subdirs

UPD2: I found the problem. listFiles() returns null, when directory is empty.

Comment: What do you think it should print and why?

Comment: What does it print in Windows?

Comment: Wow ) Shure... it's array. It's work correct. First of my troubles actualy was NullPointerException, when I passed File dir into my function. dir != null, but I have Exception anyway, when do:
File[] list = dir.listFiles();
    for (File f : list) {
...

Comment: I tried to print dir.listFiles() before I passed it into function and after. Before: I got list of files only in current dir without nested dirs and files. After: I got list with all nested files and dirs...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a special method to print arrays.  :P  Try

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dir.listFiles()));
```

It does the same thing of Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how the program is working properly in windows, it should not work in windows as well.

The method `dir.listFiles()` returns array of `File` objects, therefore you must use something like:

```
File[] files = dir.listFiles();

for (File file : files) {
    System.out.println(file);
}
```

to get correct output.